How do I show that if there are more than 2 types in a signaling game, then multiple equilibria satisfy the intuitive criterion?
I'm trying to figure out why in a signaling game with more than 2 types, multiple equilibria with different equilibrium strategies satisfy the intuitive criterion.
Take the classic Spence job market signaling game as an example. We know when there are 2 types, only one kind of equilibria satisfies the intuitive criterion. However, if why multiple equilibria survive given more than 2 types?
Suppose a worker with productivity $\theta\in\{\theta_L,\theta_H\}$, prior the entering the labor market, the worker can obtain education $e\geq 0$ at cost $c(e,\theta)$. Education is less costly for high type workers; that is, $c_1(e,\theta_H)<c_1(e,\theta_L)$ with $c_1(e,\theta)>0$. Two firms observe the education level of the worker but not his productivity. Firms believe that the probability of $\theta_H$ is $\lambda\in (0,1)$. Following any level of education $e$, the firms have the same belief $\mu(e)$ that the worker's type is $\theta_H$. Given belief $\mu(e)$, the firms must offer the same wage: $w(e)=\mu(e)\theta_H+[1-\mu(e)]\theta_L$. We can show that there is a separating equilibrium with $e^*(\theta_H)=e$ iff and only if $e\in [\hat{e},\bar{e}]$, and there is a pooling equilibrium with $e^*(\theta_H)=e$ iff and only if $e\in [0,\underline{e}]$, where

$\hat{e}$ be such that the low type is indifferent between $(\theta_L,0)$ and $(\theta_H,\hat{e})$, where $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is (wage, education)
Let $\bar{e}$ be such that the high type is indifferent between $(\theta_L,0)$ and $(\theta_H,\bar{e})$
Let $\underline{e}$ be such that the low type is indifferent between $(\theta_L,0)$ and $(E(\theta),\underline{e})$

The only equilbria that survives the intuitive criterion are the separating equilibria with $e^*(\theta_H)=\hat{e}$. How do I show that it is not the case when there are more than 2 types?


Please provide the source for the claim that you want to prove.



Please provide the exact claim that you want to prove. There are many kind of signalling games, and it is easy to produce some (e.g. with finite action spaces) which don't even have multiple equilibria.


@Giskard I'm very sorry. I've added more context

Please provide a reference for what you mean by "classic Spence job market signaling game"! Most people encounter this in a lecture or textbook, where the game is usually refined and/or simplified from the "classic" version that appeared in the original paper.

For both clarity and self-containedness it would be best if you just defined the exact game in the body of your question. If you look around the SE, you will see that there are several posters who put a lot of effort into their questions, to make them clear and easily accessible for other people.

@Giskard I added more context.

Much better. Still, where do you get the claims? Giving an exact quatition and reference would still significantly improve the question.

@Giskard Actually, the claim is from my problem set. Please see here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qaKJJtglg6HWkr_cYCWxV5K-SN6Et-uU/view?usp=drive_link

Excellent, thank you for the referrence. Next time please start with this.

"Make sure to reference all sources (if any) you used in solving the questions" hey, so, if someone provides an answer to your Q, will you reference it?

@Giskard Yes I will, and I have already referenced it quite a few times.
